# JTextField creating copies of itself every time something is typed in it

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am getting some very bizarre behavior when using JTextField in BoxLayout. Here's the code that produces the issue:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(new Dimension(900,500));
    f.getContentPanel().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    f.setLayout(new BoxLayout(f.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    
    JLabel boxOne = new JLabel();
    boxOne.setBackground(new Color(33,255,240,75));
    boxOne.setOpaque(true);
    boxOne.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(900,50));
    boxOne.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(900,50));
    boxOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900,50));
    boxOne.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    boxOne.setText("This is the first box.");
    
    JTextField boxTwo = new JTextField();
    boxTwo.setBackground(new Color(33,255,240,75));
    boxTwo.setOpaque(true);
    boxTwo.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(900,50));
    boxTwo.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(900,50));
    boxTwo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900,50));
    boxTwo.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    
    f.add(boxOne);
    f.add(boxTwo);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

What I expect is a window with boxOne displayed at the top, then boxTwo displayed under it. This is the result you get when you make boxTwo a JLabel instead of a JTextField.
[This looks as desired.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5GEI.png)

What I get instead is boxOne split in two vertically.
[This is definitely not the desired result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmobc.png)

Even more bizarre, when typing text in boxTwo, it seems to make copies of itself in the same position.
[boxTwo bizarre overlap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OQwV.png)

What I'm aiming for is to have boxOne at the top, unbroken, and boxTwo underneath it, able to type in it without the strange behavior described here. I'm new to Java so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: 1) `new Color(33,255,240,75)` Swing does not work well with translucent colors. 2) To encourage people to test code, post a [mre].

Comment: When laying out components, avoid using setMinimumSize, setMaximumSize and setPreferredSize. Instead, get it done using the features in the LayoutManager (BoxLayout, GridLayout etc.) you use.

Answer (score 1):

Because you set opaque to true, Swing is assuming the label and textbox background are NOT translucent and is not clearing the region being painted by the background color before the background is painted. It then proceeds to paint the background using a rectangle using the background color set for the component. This overlays a new rectangle every time it paints, every time you type a key for example. This is why it looks like it's duplicating the control, even though it's not.

If you set opaque to false, it won't even try to paint the background.

Remove the alpha channel from those background colors and you should be good.

Comment: *Remove the alpha channel from those background colors* - but then you won't have transparency. If you really want transparency then check out: [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for a solution.